# Funcion dividir solo retorna NaN

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Estoy practicando el manejo de errores en Js, para ello he creado una arrow function que toma 2 numeros como parametro para retornar el cociente. Solo retorna NaN

```
let div = (n1,n2) => n1/n2
try  {
if (isNaN(div(10/0))) {
    throw new Error("no se puede dividir entre 0")
}
console.log(div((10/2)))
} catch (error) {
console.log(`Se produjo ${error}`)
} finally {
console.log("vuelva a intentarlo")
console.log(div(10/2))
}
```

[image: DEBUG CONSOLE]

el problema es que mi funcion solo retorna NaN y el el bloque finally deberia imprimir 5

Comment: ¿y el problema es...?

Comment: por ejemplo en console.log del bloque finally deberia devolver 5 pero siguie siendo NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nótese los cambios: Reemplazo de un `/` por una `,`

```
let div = (n1,n2) => n1/n2;
try  {
if (isNaN(div(10,0))) {
    throw new Error("no se puede dividir entre 0");
}
console.log(div((10,2)))
} catch (error) {
console.log(`Se produjo ${error}`);
} finally {
console.log("vuelva a intentarlo");
console.log(div(10,2));
}
```

Comment: la verdad le di muchas vueltas a esto y jamas note ese detalle! muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te fue de utilidad, te pido que marques como aceptada la respuesta, de este modo colaboras con la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Gracias.